# Jmeter: Can we change the username & password in a recorded Login page

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have recorded login page and exported to JMX.
In Post method, i am giving invalid username and password,  but test cases are passing.
It should fail ideally. Does recorded script always PASS?

Regards,
Praveen

Comment: Please post your JMX file or HTTP Sample here.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful so if your application responds with "invalid credentials" message but having status code of `200` - JMeter will mark the request as "passed".

If you want JMeter to conditionally consider request as failed if i.e. "Welcome" text is missing or login form is still present you will need to add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to your request and specify pass/fail criteria there.